# $S$-matrix commutation with Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, scattering, hamiltonian, s-matrix-theory

I know from scattering theory that $S$-matrix and the free Hamiltonian $H_{0}$ commute due to energy conservation of incident and outgoing asymptotic states, but can the $S$-matrix and $H = H_{0} + V$, with $V$ the interaction potential between the particle and the target, commute? What would happen in that scenario?